# Wordpress theme mobile view troubles

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using megashop theme inside WordPress and I want answers to some questions:

How do I change a setting only in "less than desktop size" view? and not in desktop view.

Like the meta slider which on desktop view is fine but is overlapping the search bar in a resized version.

Cart, compare icons on products(ecommerce site) not centered.

And text suddenly showing on mobile view beneath an icon.

Answer (score -1):

I believe, that you can fix all these things via custom CSS (if it's available in your theme). Also, you can use media query for *"less than desktop size":*

```
@media screen and (min-width: your-width)
```